# Assembly Loop for printing pixels is not working

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

I want to print a **pixel line** with a loop but *loop_x* is not working and it doesn't displaying anything, when I remove the loop content and insert static values into *x* and *y* it displays the pixels on the correct positions. What's wrong with the following *loop_x* loop? The loop needs to be **FASM** compatible.

```
org 100h
ESC equ 1Bh


;video mode 13h
mov ah, 4Fh
mov al, 2
mov bx, 13h
int 10h

mov [x], 13
mov [y], 13
mov [size], 10

loop_x:
 mov ah, 0ch
 mov al, 5
 mov bh, 0
 mov cx, x
 mov cx, y
 int 21h
 inc [x]
 dec [size]
 jnz loop_x

x rw 1
y rw 1
size rb 1
```

Comment: Why are you moving both x and y into the same register cx?

Comment: Also, your `x` and `y` are words, but your `size` is a byte. You treat them the same way with the same instructions using pointers. What assembler are you using, and have you looked at how to tell the assembler what size the operands are.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with fasm syntax, but are you sure that `mov cx, x` loads the contents of `x` into the `cx` register, rather than its address?

Comment: And as a general comment, it seems quite inefficient to keep incrementing `x` in memory and then fetching it back.  Why not keep `x` and `y` and `size` in registers throughout the loop?

Comment: `int 21h` should probably be `int 10h`. And where is the exit statement?

Comment: Can you post your working code, and also double-check that what you've posted is actually the exact code you're testing?  There are several things that look suspiciously as if you've retyped it with mistakes.

Comment: @NateEldredge: good catch; FASM `mov reg, symbol` is a mov-immediate of the address.  In this case, `B93201   mov cx,0x132`  followed by another `mov cx, 0x134` overwriting the first immediate.  `inc [x]` magically knows the operand-size based on not using a `:` after the symbol name when declaring that "variable", apparently.  But other than having that magic operand-size stuff for "variables", FASM is fairly NASM-like.